Video call using webRTC (aiortc), Socket.IO, Flask
I want to create a simple video calling webpage using webRTC or Socket.IO with Flask.
This is some of my flask code:
@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


Inside templates directory, I have index.html file:
<div class="col-lg-8  offset-lg-2">
      <h3 class="mt-5">Live Streaming</h3>
      <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}" width="100%">
 </div>

How can I use img tag for video calls instead of a video tag that Client-to-Client interact with each other?
Note: From the given code, the video can be displayed on the web browser
Sorry for the bad English
